# Check if an arc clicked in P5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

It is pretty simple to check whether a circle is clicked in P5, but I can't figure out the easy way of doing the same with an arc.

That's how I create an arc:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(10); 
  noFill();
  arc(200, 200, 200, 200, HALF_PI, PI*1.75);
}
```

and that's the way to check whether a circle is clicked:

```
function mousePressed() {
  var d = dist(mouseX, mouseY, 200,200);
  var within_diam = (d<200+width/2 && d>200-width/2);
  console.log('Circle clicked');
}
```

I can check in addition to whether a circle clicked, to ignore if the missing sector of the arc is clicked, but it looks cumbersome, and I am pretty sure that should be a right and easy way of doing it.

Comment: You can check whether the angle made by the line joining the center of the circle and the mouse position with the x-axis is in the given range (Amin, Amax)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to check for distance and angle.

The example below uses the distance correctly, but the angle calculation is not working correctly.

```js
let withinAngle = angle > angleStart && angle < angleEnd;
```

The value of the angle grows from the starting angle, until it reaches 180 degrees. The angle value then falls again. I am not sure why this happens.

[image]

```js
var pos        = { x: 200, y: 200 },
    radius     = 100,
    size       = { width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2 },
    weight     = 10,
    angleStart = Math.PI / 2,
    angleEnd   = Math.PI * 1.75,
    angleDiff  = angleEnd - angleStart;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  textFont('Arial', 16);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(weight);
  //noFill();
  arc(pos.x, pos.y, size.width, size.height, angleStart, angleEnd);
  
  let origin = createVector(pos.x, pos.y);
  drawArrow(origin, createVector(size.width / 2, 0), 'red');
  drawArrow(origin, createVector(mouseX - pos.x, mouseY - pos.y), 'blue');
  
  let target = createVector(mouseX - pos.x, (mouseY - pos.y) * -1);
  let magnitude = dist(mouseX, mouseY, pos.x, pos.y);
  let angle = origin.angleBetween(target);
  
  strokeWeight(0);
  text([
    `Target: (${target.x}, ${target.y})`,
    `Magnitude: ${magnitude.toFixed(3)}`,
    `Radians: ${(angle / Math.PI).toFixed(3)}π`,
    `Degrees: ${degrees(angle).toFixed(3)}°`
  ].join('\n'), 250, 20);
}

function mousePressed(e) {
  let origin = createVector(pos.x, pos.y);
  let target = createVector(mouseX - pos.x, (mouseY - pos.y) * -1);
  if (checkBounds(origin, target)) {
    console.log('Circle stroke clicked');
  }
}

// Check to see if the click was within the stroke weight.
// There is no angle check in here...
function checkBounds(origin, target) {
  let magnitude = dist(mouseX, mouseY, size.width, size.height);
  let withinDist = magnitude > radius && magnitude < radius + weight;
  let angle = origin.angleBetween(target);
  let withinAngle = angle > angleStart && angle < angleEnd;
  return withinDist && withinAngle;
}

/** https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/angleBetween */
function drawArrow(base, vec, myColor) {
  push();
  stroke(myColor);
  strokeWeight(3);
  fill(myColor);
  translate(base.x, base.y);
  line(0, 0, vec.x, vec.y);
  rotate(vec.heading());
  let arrowSize = 7;
  translate(vec.mag() - arrowSize, 0);
  triangle(0, arrowSize / 2, 0, -arrowSize / 2, arrowSize, 0);
  pop();
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { height: 80px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Angle is between `[0;π]`, because api function `angleBetween()` measures _absolute_ angle between two vectors without taking into consideration angle sign.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use the formula of circle collision detection, maybe isn't the better approach, but will do the job.

Let's say you have a circle A(4, 5) and a circle B(6, 8), so you would apply the formula:

**sqrt(sqr(x) + sqr(y))**

**sqrt(sqr(4 − 3) + sqr(8 − 4)) = 8.062**

So in your case the circle A would be your mouse, and the circle B would be the fixed circle, but you also can invert this.
Check the code bellow, this should work just fine.

```
var mouseRadius = 10;
var _circle = {
  x: 200, 
  y: 200, 
  r: 100
};

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  print(_circle);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(10); 
  noFill();
  arc(_circle.x, _circle.y, _circle.r * 2, _circle.r * 2, HALF_PI, PI*1.75);
}

function mousePressed() {
  if (isColliding(mouseX, mouseY, _circle.x, _circle.y, _circle.r + mouseRadius)) {
    console.log('Circle pressed');
  }

}

function isColliding(x1, y1, x2, y2, r) {
  let part1 =  (x1 - x2 ) * ( x1 - x2 );
  let part2 = ( y1 - y2 ) * ( y1 - y2 );
  if (Math.sqrt(part1 +  part2) < r )  {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

### Edit

You can replace the function for this other function, will do the same job but this one will use less process from the computer, since do not have the SQRT anymore:

```
function isColliding(x1, y1, x2, y2, r) {
  let dx =  x2 - x1;
  let dy = y2 - y1;
  let radius = r * r;

  if ((dx * dx) + (dy* dy) < radius )  {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```